# How to show a message over leading selection cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with a custom `ListSelectionModel`, which contains a custom selection mode. This selection mode ensures that a selection is only made in one row, but with multiple cells. When a user clicks selects some cells in the table, the selected cells are all in the same row as the first selected cell.

Now I want to create a small message above the upper-right corner of the leading selection cell, which displays some data, i.e. the count of the selected cells. The message should be moved when the leading selection is changed.

But how do I do that? It is not a Tooltip as it is intended to be shown when user clicks into the table and selects cells and not by hovering over it.

Any suggestions?

best regards,
htz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively (not very pretty but works quite well), you can take advantage of the fact that JTable is a JComponent like all others and therefore you can add child components to it. All you have to do, is make sure to size and locate properly your component (this is only because JTable uses a null-layout).

Here is a small demo with a JLabel that displays the number of selected items. The label is automatically positioned on the first visible row, unless it is the current lead selection, in which case, the label is moved to the second visible row:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class TestTable {

    protected void initUI() {
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            colNames.add("Col-" + (i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                row.add("Cell " + (i + 1) + "-" + (j + 1));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        table = new JTable(data, colNames);
        someText = new JLabel();
        someText.setOpaque(true);
        table.add(someText);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int count = table.getSelectedRowCount();
                someText.setText("You currently have selected " + count + " item" + (count > 1 ? "s" : ""));
                layoutLabel();
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                layoutLabel();
            }
        });
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JLabel someText;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;

    private void layoutLabel() {
        someText.setSize(someText.getPreferredSize());
        Point location = scrollpane.getViewport().getViewRect().getLocation();
        int leadSelectionIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
        if (leadSelectionIndex > -1) {
            if (table.rowAtPoint(location) == leadSelectionIndex) {
                location.y += table.getRowHeight(leadSelectionIndex);
            }
        }
        someText.setLocation(location);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I just changed the Listener to a `TableColumnModelListener` to listen to changes in the column selection and edited the `layoutLabel()`-method to layout the label at the upper-right corner of the leading selection index. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- you can to set `Locations` for [ToolTip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) with the similair effect like as in MsExcell,

> it is not a Tooltip as it is intended to be shown when user clicks into the table and selects cells and not by hovering over it.

- you can to use `JPopup` / `JWindow` instead of `ToolTip`, for non_editable contens
- `JPopup` / `JWindow` by default can't contains editable `JComponent` (`JTextComponents`)
- for user input you can to use undecorated `JDialod` only

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is to implement a per-component glassPane (one of the many roles of JLayer for 1.7, JXLayer for 1.6) like shown below. Note that I didn't try to prettify the location (as @Guillaume did). Also, you'll have to modify the Rob's DragLayout a bit to guarantee that the box is shown inside the table area.

```
public static class ToolTipUI extends LayerUI<JTable> {
    private JLayer<JTable> layer;
    private JToolTip toolTip;

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        this.layer = (JLayer) c;
        installGlassPane();
        installListeners();
    }

    private void installListeners() {
        ListSelectionListener l = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
                updateToolTip();
            }

        };
        getTable().getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(l);
        getTable().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(l);
    }

    private void updateToolTip() {
        int[] selectedColumns = getTable().getColumnModel().getSelectedColumns();
        int selectedRow = getTable().getSelectedRow();
        if (selectedRow < 0 || selectedColumns.length == 0) {
            setToolTipText("");
        } else {
            String text = "selected cells: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedColumns.length; i++) {
                text += " " + selectedColumns[i];
            }
            setToolTipText(text);
        }
    }

    private void setToolTipText(String string) {
        toolTip.setTipText(string);
        Rectangle cellBounds = getTable().getCellRect(getTable().getSelectedRow(), 0, false);
        toolTip.setLocation(cellBounds.getLocation());
        doLayout(layer);
    }

    @Override
    public void doLayout(JLayer<? extends JTable> l) {
        super.doLayout(l);
        l.getGlassPane().doLayout();
    }

    private JTable getTable() {
        return layer.getView();
    }

    private void installGlassPane() {
        toolTip = ((JComponent) layer.getView()).createToolTip();
        layer.getGlassPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        // DragLayout by Rob Camick http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/
        layer.getGlassPane().setLayout(new DragLayout());
        layer.getGlassPane().add(toolTip);
        layer.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
    }

}

// usage:
JTable table = new JTable(new AncientSwingTeam());
JLayer layer = new JLayer<JTable>(table, new ToolTipUI());
```